# How to try all possible paths?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to try all possible paths, branching every time I hit a certain point. There are <128 possible paths for this problem, so no need to worry about exponential scaling.

1. I have a player that can take steps through a field. The player
   takes a step, and on a step there could be an encounter.
2. There are two options when an encounter is found: i) Input 'B' or ii) Input 'G'.
3. I would like to try both and continue repeating this until the end of the field is reached. The end goal is to have tried all possibilities.

Here is the template, in Python, for what I am talking about (`Step` object returns the next step using `next()`):

```
from row_maker_inlined import Step

def main():
    initial_stats = {'n':1,'step':250,'o':13,'i':113,'dng':0,'inp':'Empty'}
    player = Step(initial_stats)
    end_of_field = 128

    # Walk until reaching an encounter:
    while player.step['n'] < end_of_field:
        player.next()
        if player.step['enc']:
            print 'An encounter has been reached.'
#           Perform an input on an encounter step:
            player.input = 'B'

#           Make a branch of player?
#           perform this on the branch:
#           player.input = 'G'
#   Keep doing this, and branching on each encounter, until the end is reached.
```

As you can see, the problem is rather simple. Just I have no idea, as a beginner programmer, how to solve such a problem.

I believe I may need to use recursion in order to keep branching. But I really just do  not understand how one 'makes a branch' using recursion, or anything else.

What kind of solution should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at search algorithms like breath first search (BFS) and depth first search (DFS).

Wikipedia has this as the pseudo-code implementation of BFS:

```
  procedure BFS(G, v) is
    let Q be a queue
    Q.enqueue(v)
    label v as discovered
    while Q is not empty
        v← Q.dequeue()
        for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
            if w is not labeled as discovered
                Q.enqueue(w)
                label w as discovered
```

Essentially, when you reach an "encounter" you want to add this point to your queue at the end. Then you pick your FIRST element off of the queue and explore it, putting all its children into the queue, and so on. It's a non-recursive solution that is simple enough to do what you want.

DFS is similar but instead of picking the FIRST element form the queue, you pick the last. This makes it so that you explore a single path all the way to a dead end before coming back to explore another.

Good luck!

Comment: DFS doesn't require an additional data structure (queue) for keeping track of where to search next. It just uses the stack. For the sake of simplicity, I'd recommend using DFS.

Comment: Yeah, what @DaoWen said is a good point. They both have pros and cons, this is a pro of DFS.